# Поиск посылок и изменения статуса отправки прямо с админ панели

Tags: php, база-данных, post, форма

хочу сделать что-то типа поиска посылок и изменения статуса отправки прямо с админ панели и для этого вывел список всех кодов в виде ссылок и сделал форму для ввода статуса и вторую страницу для самого добавления, но все что выводиться это трек код и все, никаких ошибок и ничего в базе, пробовал через первую форму с одной страницей, но там тоже не сработало

1 страница с выбором:

```php
<?php 
$host = '127.0.0.1'; // адрес сервера 
$database = 'mail'; // имя базы данных
$user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
$password = ''; // пароль

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
    or die("Ошибка подключения" . @mysqli_error($link));
 ?>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Изменение Статуса Посылки</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<div class="centerd" style="margin-left: 500px;margin-top: 300px;">
<?php $status = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `post` ");
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($status)) {
    ?><a href="new_stat.php?key=<?php echo $result['track'];?>"><?php echo $result['track']; ?></a>;
    <?php
    echo "<br>";
   } ?>
</div>
```

вторая страница с написанием статуса

```php
<?php 
$host = '127.0.0.1'; // адрес сервера 
$database = 'mail'; // имя базы данных
$user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
$password = ''; // пароль
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
    or die("Ошибка подключения" . @mysqli_error($link));
$key = $_POST['key'];   
$text = $_POST['status'];

 ?>
новый статус для <?php  echo $key; ?>:
<form action="change_stat.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="status" placeholder="новый статус">
<input type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $key; ?> " name="key">
<input type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $text; ?> " name="stat">
<input type="submit" value="изменить" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
$res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `track` = '$key'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if( $count > 0 ) { 
  echo "<pre>";
  $status = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT `status` FROM `post` WHERE `track` = '$track'");
  $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($status);
  echo "Текущий статус: ";
  echo $result['status'];
  echo "<pre>";
  echo "IP: ";
  echo $result['Ip'];
  echo "<pre>";
  echo "Date: ";
  echo $result['time'];
} else {
    exit('не удалось найти такой трек номер!');
}
 ?>
```

и 3 страница с самой обработкой и редактированием

```php
<?php 
$host = '127.0.0.1'; // адрес сервера 
$database = 'mail'; // имя базы данных
$user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
$password = ''; // пароль
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
    or die("Ошибка подключения" . @mysqli_error($link));
$key = $_GET['key']; 
$text = "123";

  $edit  = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `post` SET `status` = '$text' WHERE `track` = '$key' ");
    echo $key;
    echo $status;
    $status = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `track` = '$key'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($status);
    echo "Текущий статус: ";
    echo $result['status'];
?>
```

Comment: Извините, но PHP изначально был сделан, чтобы вот такого не было `echo "<pre>";` — то есть не PHP разметку должен выводить, а PHP в разметку «вставляться. Я бы рад помочь, но 80% времени и энергии мозга потратиться на то, чтобы код проанализировать текущий :) Вам же самому трудно сейчас и потом будет код поддерживать... Нужно стараться, даже если никакой фреймворк не используете: разделять логику от вывода хотя бы...

Comment: И скриншот интерфейса бы не помешал с той функцией, которую вам нужно помочь решить — сразу будет проще понять о чем речь.

Comment: Почитайте эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Чтобы вам помогли, задайте вопрос по конкретному модулю, который не работает, а не выкладывайте все подряд.